# Is the space of trace class operators finitely representable in an $L^1$-space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am interested in knowing whether the space of trace class operators is (crudely) finitely representable in an $L^1$-space. I suspect that the answer is negative but I am unable to find any argument confirming my intuition.

As for motivation, I am working on matrix-valued versions of some inequalities coming from harmonic analysis, and I would like to know if the generalisation I seek is non-trivial, if true.

Definition:
A Banach space $X$ is said to be crudely finitely representable in a Banach space $Y$ if there exists a constant $C>0$ such that every finite-dimensional subspace $V$ of $X$ is $C$-isomorphic to a subspace of $Y$, i.e. there exists an isomorphism $T: V \to T(V) \subset Y$ satisfying $\|T\|\cdot \|T^{-1}\| \leqslant C$.

Comment: crudely finitely represented in an $L^1$-space - is there a definition?

Comment: http://books.google.de/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=(crudely)+finitely+representable&source=bl&ots=4dwZK2DBPv&sig=LbCyZJja_556KEeE85NHhbWJMB0&hl=de&sa=X&ei=MjCrUr2sJKO24wSop4HABA&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=(crudely)%20finitely%20representable&f=false

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Marc; I've added the definition to the body of the question.

Comment: The answer is no, but right now I don't recall a proof.

Comment: BTW: A separable Banach space $X$ is crudely finitely representable in an $L_1$ space iff $X$ is isomorphic to a subspace of $L_1(0,1)$. This is proved in the Lindenstrauss-Pelczynski "Absolutely summing operators" paper. (Use ultra products to embed into an abstract $L_1$ space and quote Kakutani's representation theorem.)

Comment: @BillJohnson: Thank you for your comment. Do I understand correctly that it is still not obvious how to prove that $S_1$ is not isomorphic to a subspace of $L_1(0,1)$?

Comment: Certainly not obvious, Mateusz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deduce that $S_1$ is not finitely crudely representable in an $L_1$ space from the  paper

Pisier, Gilles Some results on Banach spaces without local unconditional structure. Compositio Math. 37 (1978), no. 1, 3–19.

However, I think that the result you want might have been known earlier.  Maybe it follows from Kwapien and Pelczynski's "Main triangle projection" paper, which I do not now have at hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer; it crossed my mind that local unconditional structure might be relevant. To be more specific, the result follows from theorem 2.1, because $L^1$ has local unconditional structure (as na $\mathcal{L}^1$-space) and finite cotype.

Comment: On a tangential note, do we know what are the reflexive subspaces of $S_1$? At least do we know if they are super-reflexive?

Answer (score 6):

The question was answered long ago. But my favorite answer (to myself) is: The trace class $S_1$ has not Analytic UMD property while commutative $L^1$ has this property. Since Analytic UMD property is a local property, it follows immediately that $S_1$ is not finitely representable in $L^1$.