# Name for certain property of equivalent norms on finite-dimensional subspaces of a Banach space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $X=(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space and suppose that $F\subset X$ is a finite-dimensional subspace. There is then an equivalent norm $|\cdot|$ on $F$ such that $|\cdot|$ is induced by an inner product on $F$ (i.e. $|\cdot|$ will satisfy the parallelogram law) and it follows that
\begin{equation} c_{(F,|\cdot|)}|x|\leq\|x\|\leq C_{(F,|\cdot|)}|x| \end{equation}
for some constants $c,C>0$ and for all $x\in F$. **Here is my main question:** is there a name for the following property?

There exists $M\geq 1$ such that for every finite-dimensional subspace $F\subset X$, there is an equivalent norm $|\cdot|$ on $F$ that is induced by an inner product on $F$ and is such that $1\leq \frac{C}{c}\leq M$.

Clearly, any Hilbert space has this property by taking $M=1$ and $|\cdot|=\|\cdot\|$. Are there examples of non-Hilbert spaces that have this property? Is this property related somehow to the type/cotype of $X$?

Comment: The property has no quantifier on $c,C$. Probably you define $c,C$ as functions of $(F,|\cdot|)$ in the first paragraph but you could be more explicit.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: This is finite representability. Please see the definition in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151758/is-the-space-of-trace-class-operators-finitely-representable-in-an-l1-space

Comment: See also https://books.google.ca/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=(crudely)+finitely+representable&source=bl&ots=4dwZK2DBPv&sig=LbCyZJja_556KEeE85NHhbWJMB0&sa=X&ei=MjCrUr2sJKO24wSop4HABA#v=onepage&q=(crudely)%20finitely%20representable&f=false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your condition implies that $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space with isomorphism constant at most $M^2$. The distance condition implies that both type 2 constant and cotype 2 constant of $X$ is bounded by $M$. By Kwapien theorem the Banach-Mazur distance of $X$ to a Hilbert space is bounded by type 2 constant times cotype 2 constant.

As a reference see e.g., Albiac-Kalton.

Comment: Got it. I had a feeling something like this was the case. Thanks, Bunyamin

Comment: That is a perfectly fine answer, but using Kwapien's Theorem is a bit of an overkill. It is an elementary compactness argument that the condition implies that X is isomorphic to a Hilbert space with isomorphism constant at most M.